# Unknown column in where clause when nested selection

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to get results from different tables in one query. But got the unknown column error.

```
SET sql_mode = '';

SELECT 
    e_mills.m_id, 
    e_mills.mill_name, 
    e_cities.city_name, 
    e_sugardata.mill_closing_stock, 
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(mill_closing_stock SEPARATOR ', ') 
        FROM (
            SELECT mill_closing_stock 
            FROM `e_sugardata` 
            WHERE m_id = e_mills.m_id 
            GROUP BY date_added 
            ORDER BY date_added DESC 
            LIMIT 0,4
        ) AS mill_closing_stock
    ) AS stock_chart
FROM e_mills 
    INNER JOIN e_cities 
        ON e_mills.city_id = e_cities.city_id 
    INNER JOIN e_sugardata 
        ON e_sugardata.m_id = e_mills.m_id 
ORDER BY e_mills.province_id
```

**ERROR**

> #1054 - Unknown column 'e_mills.m_id' in 'where clause'

**UPDATE**

Same query is working on my computer but not on other computer

**UPDATE 2 working on MySQL 8**

[MySQL 8 DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9a27f58e2bb3ba464e3898fa934eaba2)

Comment: You cannot refer to external column via intermediate nested level. Do not use correlated subquery, add it as common subquery into FROM with proper joining condition.

Comment: This query is working on my computer but not the other one

Comment: Different MySQL versions?

Comment: BTW, the GROUP BY is invalid and expected to raise an error. (And will do so on newer MySQL versions, unless in compatibility mode.)

Comment: How can I run this query in previous MySQL version

Comment: can you try to replace sub with this ? :FROM `e_sugardata` e
            WHERE e.m_id = e_mills.m_id 
            GROUP BY e.date_added 
            ORDER BY e.date_added DESC

Comment: The problem is in the MySQL version. Compare the simple test for [5.7](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d7e6e66508b9a7197d85a0dda24e2f22) and [8](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d7e6e66508b9a7197d85a0dda24e2f22). MySQL 5.7 does not "see" the column being accessed from a deeply nested query.

Comment: @id'7238 How can we do this in MySQL 5.7

Comment: Edit your question and add a link to a working fiddle for your MySQL 8 query with sample data.

Comment: @id'7238 check the updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid an error in MySQL 5.7, you need to get rid of the nested query with a limit. Instead of a LIMIT clause, you can use the SUBSTRING_INDEX function. Also, the GROUP BY clause is unnecessary, especially since it does not work without changing sql_mode if the column list of the SELECT clause does not match the GROUP BY list.

```
-- SET sql_mode = ''; -- no more needed.

SELECT 
  e_mills.m_id, 
  e_mills.mill_name, 
  e_cities.city_name, 
  e_sugardata.mill_closing_stock, 
  (
    SELECT 
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        GROUP_CONCAT(mill_closing_stock ORDER BY date_added DESC SEPARATOR ', '
        ), ', ', 4
      )
    FROM `e_sugardata` 
    WHERE m_id = e_mills.m_id 
  ) AS stock_chart
FROM e_mills 
    INNER JOIN e_cities 
        ON e_mills.city_id = e_cities.city_id 
    INNER JOIN e_sugardata 
        ON e_sugardata.m_id = e_mills.m_id 
ORDER BY e_mills.province_id
```

db<>fiddle: [MySQL 5.7](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=132a540146c358ed19f7839a21f4a537) and [MySQL 8](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=132a540146c358ed19f7839a21f4a537)